# UK Visit Visa Bank Statement Monthly Income, should I put all the salary and withdraw my expenditures or I can only deposit my savings?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, proof-provenance-of-funds

My monthly salary is 650 USD which I receive in cash each month. (transactions in my country are mostly cash-based)

I know the ideal bank statement would show a deposit of 650 USDs payday and a withdraw of 200 USDs during the month, so the net saving would be 450 USDs each month.

But I am, due to logistic purposes, planning to directly deposit the net saving (450$) each month at payday with no withdraws and explain in my cover letter that this account is only a saving account for the UK trip.

Is it ok to do that?

Comment: Do you have salary slips to confirm your stated income, albeit received in cash? UKVI typically want to see evidence of both the source *and* the amount. Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab

Comment: The more you deviate from what UKVI wants to see, the greater the chances your application will be denied.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica OTOH, the UKVI should know the culture at OP's country and hopefully would not be too surprised that he follows local practices, as long as he can reasonably justify his lifestyle.